# how do I get the username of the user who started a build in hudson

Tags: java, groovy, hudson, hudson-plugins

I'm using the groovy post build plugin.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

I'd like to access the username of the user who started the build. What is the correct variable for this?

Comment: If it was just a typo or an easy mistake, than please delete the question.

Comment: There was a typo in the orginal title of this question it said "user whos tarted a build" I've fixed the question title but need an answer to it still!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm running something that looks like this:

```
def build = manager.build   // "manager" for Groovy Postbuild plugin, only
def usercause=build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserCause)
def thename=usercause.userName
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Javadoc for the `build` variable, there is a method `getCauses()`. I think you can start there.

https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/index.html?hudson/model/Run.html

It's called `causes` because a user is not the only cause why a job gets build. SCM commits, time triggered or upward or downward build can also cause a build.

Answer (score 0):

jenkins 1.561

def userName = manager.build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause).userName